# .htaccess Not Working Despite AllowOverride All

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

- Apache HTTP Server 2.2.22
- Arch Linux i686

I am using the [HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess) with WordPress Multisite, which requires two .htaccess files. I’m not sure which would take precedence, so I included the entire H5BP code in each, up until the WP-specific stuff, noted here:

Under `/`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
# END WordPress
```

Under `/wordpress/`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

All of the WordPress code seems to be in working order; my site is functional. However, the Boilerplate code does not. I’ve had no luck with e.g. mod_headers or mod_deflate taking effect, even though they are being loaded in httpd.conf, and my VirtualHost has `AllowOverride All` set.

For example:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
  # `mod_headers` can't match based on the content-type, however, we only
  # want to send this header for HTML pages and not for the other resources
  <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svg|svgz|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
      Header unset X-UA-Compatible
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

…will not set the `X-UA-Compatible` header. However, if I do it directly in PHP, with `<?php header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1'); ?>`, then it does appear in the response.

Similarly, the following does not GZIP anything:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are all necessary mods (mod_rewrite, mod_headers, mod_deflate, mod_setenvif, mod_filter) installed on your machine?

Comment: Is there anything in your apache error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you resolved it by now. I just wanted to point out that this helped me resolve my issue.

```
# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
# (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
#  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
#  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
```

The above snip you posted while searching for answers clued me in. Was mod_filter enabled? I checked and nope it wasn't which would stop this in its tracks.

Like Honoki said make sure (mod_rewrite, mod_headers, mod_deflate, mod_setenvif, mod_filter) are installed and/or enabled for Boilerplates's mod_deflate section to work.